# Project Reference format in a vcproj file(vs2008)

Tags: visual-studio-2008, vcproj

Here I am again asking for help.
Can anyone please show me a sample of a vcproj file with a project reference(not assembly reference) or could at least show me the format how is it written in the file.

I have searched in the internet for samples but cant find one with project reference only assembly refs like these

```
<References>
    <AssemblyReference
        RelativePath="System.dll"
        AssemblyName="System, Version=2.0.0.0, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089, processorArchitecture=MSIL"
        MinFrameworkVersion="131072"
    />
    </References>
```

so can anyone please give me a sample, as i need to handle these references by reading them as an XML.

Thanks you very muchh

```
<ProjectReference
        ReferencedProjectIdentifier="{178A5D9D-1F3E-49B1-9190-916D0864BD5C}"
        RelativePathToProject=".\ReleaseNotes\ReleaseNotes.csproj"
    />
```

Comment: Why not create such a reference and open the solution file in a text editor to see how it was added?

Comment: Ok now I have got the format thanks. My next question is, is there a way to get the MinFrameworkVersion="131072" programatically? Because I need to convert these projectref to an assemblyref and i do this just by modifying the proj file as a txt. Or is it safe to not include the MinFrameworkVersion="131072" in the file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The references in the .vcproj concern only managed projects, so if you want to reference  native projects there are other ways to do it:

- reference project in libs added.
- in the .sln file reference that P1 is dependant to P2.
- in the source code use #pragma comment(lib,..)